# How can I draw a rectangle to my canvas from my main class?

Tags: java, canvas, awt

I know I can do it with a bufferstrategy (inside a loop), but is there a way to do it without a bufferstrategy (inside a loop)?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JavaApplication28 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Title");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyCanvas mycanvas = new MyCanvas();
        f.add(mycanvas);
        f.setSize(400,250);
        f.setVisible(true); 

        //I would like to create the rectangle on the canvas here, which is possible with bufferstrategy

    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class MyCanvas extends Canvas{
    public MyCanvas (){
        
    }

    //Do I call paint() in my main class, something like mycanvas.paint().drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100)? Is there such syntax?
 
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember if AWT canvases have repaint()... haven't used them in 20 years :)
Hold a collection of "rendered" objects in the canvas and just add/remove and repaint as you see fit.

```
public class MyCanvas extends Canvas{
    private final List<Shape> shapes;
    public MyCanvas (){
        shapes = new ArrayList();
    }

    public List<Shape> renderedShapes() {
       return shapes;
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        // the shapes are created in the main class but once you add them to the renderedShapes() array of this canvas, you have access to them and the graphics context at this point and can render them.
        for (Shape s : shapes) {               
           renderShape(g, s);
        }
    }
}

private void renderShape(Graphics g, Shape shape) {
   if (Shape instanceof Rectangle) {
          Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)shape;
          g.drawRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
   } else if (Shape instanceof Circle) {
       Circle circle = (Circle)shape;
       g.drawCircle(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius);
   }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
   canvas.renderedShapes().add(new Rectangle(0,0,10,10));
   canvas.repaint();

}
```

Comment: Can you expand `// render your shape` I can't think of anything to put there. Since Rectangle is created in the main class. Is it `g.s`?

Comment: Elaborated. Don't take the added stuff as "working" because I didn't test it. But the gist of it is to determine the type of shape and draw it using the graphics parameter.

Comment: and that RenderShape(Graphics, Shape) method should be in the MyCanvas class... but for the life of me I can't edit it in this garbage web view without borking the entire indentation :p

Comment: What should I replace `var` from `for (var s : shapes)`?

Comment: Is it `(Shapes s : shapes)`?

Comment: It works. Thanks. I edit it, remove the circle, because I just want rectangles.

Comment: I wish I can edit your answer to show the final correct version. But stackoverflow says "Suggested edit queue is full"

Comment: Don't extend Canvas. When using Swing you should extend JPanel (or JComponent) and then override paintComponent(...).

Comment: Ah, good point Camickr. I remember now why I haven't used an AWT canvas in 20 years.

Comment: Good call on deleting that answer. Congrats on enough rep. to make comments.